# Regex another line

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Hello I've studying regex and I want know why:

This code:

```
<?PHP
$str = '<TD class=""><option value="123">abc</option>
</TD>
        <TD class=""><option value="123">abcwda</option>
        </TD>';

preg_match_all('#<TD([\S\s]+)</TD>#s', $str, $tabela);
?>
```

Return:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  class=""><option value="123">abc</option>
</TD>
        <TD class=""><option value="123">abcwda</option>

)
```

And why does it not return:

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  class=""><option value="123">abc</option>
    [1] =>  class=""><option value="123">abcwda</option>

)
```

?

Comment: You should also learn that  using `REGEX`  is not a good approach for parsing `HTML` instead use `DOMDocument`

Comment: Don't be greedy...

Comment: ...that does not help you, it actually works "against" you. Don't use caps, ever. bit of a tip for you ;-) if your "code" contains caps, then that's a different animal.

Comment: Why do you think caps makes it easier to read? If that was the case then all books/webpages/ etc. would be in caps

Comment: Is the html tags important to you? If not, use a different too. Regex and html is not a good combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) `+`. Use its [lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions) counterpart (`+?`):

```
preg_match_all('#<TD(.+?)</TD>#s', $str, $tabela);
```

Please also note that since you're using the `/s` modifier, `.` will match newline characters so you don't need the `[\S\s]` construct.